# Imprimir conteúdo do banco, com quebra de linha

Tags: php, html

Tenho um conteúdo no banco, que tem quebra e linha:

```
linha 1
linha 2
linha 3
```

Quando imprimo num `<textarea>`, as quebras funcionam perfeitamente.

Mas se imprimo em uma `<td>`, ele não faz as quebras.

Existe algum comando para que respeite as quebras ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o `nl2br`:

```
echo nl2br($string);
```

[Manual oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: já achou a resposta? nem tempo pra responder :)

Comment: Já ! rs... nestes casos eu excluo ou posto ? Geralmente posto para ajudar quem pesquisa...

Comment: Você só marca a resposta como aceita como de costume